# qtCreator change default toolchain for new projects

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw, qt-creator

As the title says, my question is simple: how do I change the default toolchain that is used for new projects? In my case **qtCreator always defaults to the auto-detected MSVCR**, which I cannot even seem to remove. But I want it to use the mingw64 I added manually. Currently for each new project I have to change this from the project options.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want but you might add a custom project template http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-project-wizards.html

Comment: `Tools` -> `Options...` -> `Build & Run` -> `Kits` -> `Make Default`, doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Okay, I was using an older version of the creator (2.5.2) and it has "toolchains" instead of kits. Anyway I guess it was about time I upgraded. Both the comments helped, thanks.